# Passing custom data to a user tag?

Tags: members, solspace-user, member-management

Attempting to customize the list of users displayed based upon a custom field in a channel entry.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="messages"}
  {exp:user:users group_id="{member_groups backspace="1"}{option_name}|{/member_groups}"}
    {email} - {group_id}
  {/exp:user:users}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

The 'member_groups' custom field will output the chosen groups in this format...

```
group_id="7|8|9"
```

No matter what, I always get the logged in super admin account as a result. Is this possible with User or do I need to use a query here?

Would really prefer to not have to use an embed since I also need to this to work for sending email notifications when a new entry is posted to the messages channel.

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you add parse="inward" to the channel entries tag as a parameter?

Comment: Same result as before - no joy.

Comment: What is the fieldtype of the `member_groups` custom field? That can make a difference. Also, did you turn on **Template Debugging** to see if `group_id=""` contains parsed and accurate data?

Comment: The field type is a multi-select that outputs in the format mentioned above. Template debugging shows the accurate data in the users tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure this will not work unless you use an embed. That said, I am not sure why using an embed would stop email notifications from working (though I do not know how and what you intend on setting that up with). I am also assuming {member_groups} is a custom channel field?

Main template:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="messages"}
  {embed="path_to/embed" member_groups="{member_groups backspace="1"}{option_name}|{/member_groups}"}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Embedded template:

```
  {exp:user:users group_id="{embed:member_groups}"}
    {email} - {group_id}
  {/exp:user:users}
```

Comment: Yes, as mentioned above 'member_groups' is my custom field. Embed won't work because this also has to fit into Postmaster to send users of the chosen member groups an email notification for new entries.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no experience with Postmaster, and don't know how it works, how it's set up, and why embeds wouldn't work. If embeds can't be used for some reason, maybe using PHP or Stash to pass the data over? It would likely be more complex, however. The goal is to circumvent parse order so that your member group ids wind up parsed before `{exp:user:users}` is.

Comment: Just going to mark your answer that it won't work. Thx!!